# django ImageField subclass, abstract value

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to subclass the Django ImageField.  This is quite complicated as I'm finding out.  There seems to be some basic ORM stuff that just isn't making sense to me, for instance:

> Where does the ORM field (ImageField) instance store the value that
> gets stored in the DB? Where does (ImageField) actually declare its db field type?

It looks likes the ImageField returns an FieldImage object with a self.name attribute contains the same value which gets stored in the db.  However, I' like to intercept that and abstract it so I can change the value without breaking the underlying operation of ImageField.  So far I'm like 20hrs in on reading through the docs and haven't come up with the answer.  Anyone successfully been able to abstract the value?  I'm trying to store a bunch of JSON that contains the relative file name, instead of just the relative file name.

example:

```
#Image Field currently stores:
'./images/products/myimage.png'

#My subclass should instead store:
"{'source':'./images/products/myimage.png','other_info':'./images/products/myimage.png'}"
```

The below is an excript from [django.db.models.fields.FieldFile](https://github.com/django/django/blob/63d239db037f02d98b7771c90422840bbb4a319a/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L86)

```
def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
        self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
        setattr(self.instance, self.field.attname, self.name)
        self._committed = True

        # Save the object because it has changed, unless save is False
        if save:
            self.instance.save()
    save.alters_data = True
```

Notice the line `setattr(self.instance, self.field.attname, self.name)`.  Its like `FieldFile` is reassigning the reference to itself that the field instance (`FileField`) is holding.  So, if I'm reading this right, `FieldFile`, would then be garbage collected and the 'name' property for the `FileField` instance would be a string?

Comment: What do you mean by abstracting the value, did you check implementation source for FileField

Comment: @iklinac - yeah, that's what's got me confused.  I think I'm following the rabbit hole to a certain extent, `FileField` returns `FieldFile` which an API proxy for the 'File' object.  It seems like the `name` attribute of `FieldFile` is what gets saved to the db.  Its a really tricky save process though.  I'll add it to the question.  My current line of thought is to write a custom descriptor for the `FieldFile`, but results have been middling so far.

Comment: By abstracting the value, I mean I want to pull it into some kind of custom object/function where I can manipulate, while still making the stock django features (models, forms, etc) interact with the value as it always was.  So my end result, could save a JSON string like described above, but anything in django that asks for the value of the image would be given the relative file name just like always.